# If filter returns nil, how do I not return empty result?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing the following filtering that returns a recipe list, filtered by given category name value.

```
filteredRecipe = filteredRecipe.filter({
    if let category = $0.valueForKey("category") as? NSManagedObject {
        if let name = category.valueForKey("name") as? String {
            return name.rangeOfString(cap) != nil
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
})
```

This filter works in association with searchBar textfield so I will possibly have random value in the textfield which will make `filteredRecipe` to hold unreliable data.

I need to make sure when the filter can't find any recipe from `filteredRecipe` with given category name value, I leave `filteredRecipe` untouched.
Currently, when there is no match, it makes `filteredRecipe` empty array `[]`. I'm not sure what part causes this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this language, but in most languages like this, you should be able to simply add another `.filter({$0 != nil})` to the end of your first `filter(...)` call. So `filteredRecipe.filter(/* your original filter code */).filter({$0 != nil })` should work no?

Comment: what about `if let name = category.valueForKey("name") as? String , a = name.rangeOfString(cap) { return a } else { return false}`

Comment: Have you tried simply returning `filteredRecipe`?

Comment: @Lawrence413 `filteredRecipe?` in place of where?

Comment: @EICaptain I get compile error on `return a` complaining `Cannot convert return expression of type Range<index>...to return type 'Bool'`

Comment: Instead of assigning directly to filteredRecipe, assign to a temporary variable with a conditional unwrap `if let filtered = filteredRecipe.filter(...) { filteredRecipe = filtered }`

Comment: @originaluser2 I was just adding a comment suggesting that :) except you would assign directly to `filteredRecipe`

Comment: `return filteredRecipe` instead of `return false`. If conditions aren't met it just gives you back the original object.

Comment: @Lawrence413 I get compile error that it has to be boolean

Comment: Ah, I see, I had misread the question. The answer @Paulw11 posted below should do what you want and keep your original list intact if the filter ended up returning an empty list.

Comment: Try @Paulw11's suggestion.

Comment: Is your `filteredRecipe` really `nil`? If no item matches the filter condition then it would be an empty array `[]`.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I was getting `[]` Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the filtering result to a temporary variable and check that it isn't empty.

```
let filtered = filteredRecipe.filter({
    if let category = $0.valueForKey("category") as? NSManagedObject {
        if let name = category.valueForKey("name") as? String {
            return name.rangeOfString(cap) != nil
    } 
    return false
})

if !filtered.isEmpty {
    filteredRecipe = filtered
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it still makes `filteredRecipe` an empty array []

Comment: In your original problem you said `filteredRecipe` was nil.  Was it, in fact, an empty array?

Comment: Actually, does `filter` return `nil` or a 0 length collection?

Comment: Sorry. My bad..it's actually `[]` not nil. I will make an edit.

Comment: @nhgrif Personally, I prefer the parentheses, but that is just 30 years of typing them automatically

Comment: @Paulw11 One pass of SwiftLint autocorrect will fix that in a jiff.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to extend `Collection` with a `selfOrNilIfEmpty` property, and use the nil coalescing operator:

```swift
extension Collection {
    var selfOrNilIfEmpty: Self? {
        return isEmpty ? nil : self
    }
}
```

and later, on your code:

```swift
let filteredRecipe = filteredRecipe.filter { ... }.selfOrNilIfEmpty ?? filteredRecipe
```

Comment: This extension generates an error: `'nil' requires a contextual type`

Comment: @turingtested there was an `?` missing after `Self`, I updated/corrected the answer, thanks

Comment: But the great benefit of this approach is that you directly can sort out unwanted results, like this: `if let filteredAndNotEmpty = filteredRecipe.filter{ ... }.selfOrNilIfEmpty { //do stuff }`